# Why datepicker is unable to show when i click on datepickers next button?

Tags: jquery, date, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

```
$(document).on('focus',".expdate",function(){
    $('.expdate').datepicker({minDate:0});
    $(this).datepicker();
    $( ".expdate" ).datepicker('option','dateFormat','dd/mm/yy');
    $( ".expdate" ).datepicker("changeMonth", true );
});
```

I'm trying to disable all previous dates and I need to show all the next days maybe 2017 december also. Date format must be `dd/mm/yy`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#appDatePick').datepicker({format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
    startDate: "today",
    endDate: '+2m',
    autoclose: true
});
```

(or)

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' });
```

use this one

Comment: Thanks for replay.Still Unable to get dd/mm/yy formate

Comment: This is bootstrap datepicker

Comment: Remove jquery.ui and insert bootstrap datepicker

Comment: $('#datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' }); use this one

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery-ui datepicker options to create the component you need:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.expdate').datepicker({
        minDate: 0,
        maxDate: new Date(2017, 11, 31),
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        changeMonth: true
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<input type="text" class="expdate">
```

You disable all previous date setting `minDate` to 0. `maxDate` lets you define the maximum selectable date (31/12/2017 in the example). Using `dateFormat` you can customize date format and you can enable month dropdown using `changeMonth`.
You can find the complete reference in the [official documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/).